# Bootstrap 4 scrollbar overflow with sticky-top

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a grid with two rows with the first being fixed to the top of the screen via sticky-top and the second with min-vh-100 so that it fills the remaining height on the screen. Content will be dynamically added to the innerHTML of the second row and I want the user to always have the first row visible as the overflow is handled automatically by a scrollbar.

The first issue is that it creates a scrollbar on document load/ready and you can scroll down so that some of the content (which I think is determined by the stick-top height) in the second row is "hidden" behind the first row. I think this is because of the sticky-top but not sure how to fix it. A scrollbar should only be made if there is overflow in the second row when content is added. I should not be able to scroll down so that content is lost behind the first row.

The second issue is that I want the scrollbar to automatically scroll as content is added to the second row. I tried playing around with the body's scrollTop and scrollHeight but couldn't get it working. In the Codepen example, I should not be able to scroll down so that "Hello" is hidden.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    label:hover {
      background: LightGray;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <form name="form" enctype="multipart/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/execute" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="row pt-2 pb-4 align-items-center justify-content-center bg-light sticky-top">

            <button class="submitbutton btn btn-info" type="submit" name="Help" value="Help">Help</button>

            <div class="ml-4 mr-4">
              <input class="form-control mt-2" type="text" name="Textbox">
            </div>

            <button class="submitbutton btn btn-success mr-4" type="submit" name="Go" value="Go">Go</button>
            <button id="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Cancel</button>

          </div>

          <div class="row bg-dark">
            <code class="pl-4 text-white min-vh-100">Hello</code>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/atye/pen/GRpMKNX)

I would like to keep the use of the rows and columns because it's part of a larger grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I would use (if I'm following you properly) is adding

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 78px); // Change the px to whatever the sticky-top is
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jeffberlin/pen/oNjGgwx)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default bootstrap css as:

codepen: https://codepen.io/Rishab2019/pen/rNOGBEz

```
.bg-light{

  position:relative!important;
}
```